# addlast()method null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception

```
public class Node {
    private String element;
    private Node next;

    public void setNext(Node newNext) {
       next = newNext;
    }

public class SLinkedList {

    protected Node head;
    protected Node tail;
    protected long size;

    public void addLast(Node newNode) {
        newNode.setNext(null);
        tail.setNext(newNode);
        tail = newNode;
        size = size + 1;
}

public class TestLinkedList {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    SLinkedList myList = new SLinkedList();

    //create 3 node
    Node m = new Node("Tom1", null);
    Node n = new Node("Tom2", null);
    Node p = new Node("Tom3", null);



    //add 1 node at the end
    myList.addLast(m);


    //print
    System.out.println(myList);
    System.out.println("Size=\t"+myList.getSize());
}
```

when executed "myList.addLast(m); it shows nullpointerexception at "tail.setNext(newNode);"
I just wanna know what happen?

Comment: Search nullpointerexception in StackOverflow can gives you lots of related examples on such failure.

Comment: Obviously it is related to uninitialized variables being accessed

Answer (score 0):

In your code,

```
tail.setNext(newNode); // tail isn't initialized yet
tail = newNode;
```

Instead do,

```
tail = newNode;    
tail.setNext(newNode);
```